# How to search and get result from database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 tables in the same database:
Table1: with follow a field named "mark_allow"

Table2: with the following fields: "header", "title", "comments"

How can I use the result of what I get "mark_allow" in Table 1 and search for the corresponding content of "comments" in Table 2 using php?

Regards,

Comment: Which is common field in both of the table??

Comment: Header in Table 2. The field "mark_allow" in Table1 contain a string like 012 or 013 etc.   Depends on this string, I would like to search for a corresponding "comment" by comparing the content of "header" field in Table2

Comment: If you want that data are dependent in both table then you have to use primary key and foreign key. hope you know about these keys in mysql.

Comment: In Table 2, "header" has primary key.

Comment: You need to give better table information. Half examples leads to a half answer.

Comment: Table1- fields are "id"(varchar)- primary key; "mark_allow"(varchar), "max_mark"(int)   Table2 - fields are "header" (varchar)-primary key; "comment"(text); "school"(varchar). They are in the same database.

Answer (score 1):

```
define("DBSERV", "yo.ur.ip.addr");     // The host you want to connect to.
define("DBUSER", "myfunctionalaccount");    // The database username. 
define("DBPASS", "superdoopersecurepassword!");    // The database password. 
define("DBNAME", "thegoods");
define("DBPORT", "3306")
#DBPORT OPTIONAL - Not required for default 3306
$mysqli = new mysqli(DBSERV, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME, DBPORT);
if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("")
$stmt->bind_param('sds', $stringparam1, $decimalparam, $stringparam2);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result( $outcome);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
echo "$output"
```

If you provide some additional information, we can better tell you how to perform a JOIN Statement that works with your database... otherwise this is a really generic answer.

```
SELECT t1.mark_allow, t2.comments
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.header = t2.header
```

Comment: Thanks but I purpose is not to JOIN the table.

Comment: Thanks but I purpose is not to JOIN the table.  What I need is to look for the corresponding content in "comment" of table 2 using the "mark_allow" field and then print it out using php.   Example: "mark_allow" contain string "01" or "013" or "012345". By searching the "header" field (which contain "01" or "013" or "012345" etc"; I can get the "comment" content correspond to say "01". This "comment" field is a text description and I would like to print it out on html page.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to make column full text in which you want to search.than you can use this query. column1 and column2 should be fulltext

**SELECT * from table where (MATCH(column1) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)>0 OR MATCH(column2) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)>0 )**

Comment: Not quite understand.. Can you elaborate? They are in 2 different table.

Comment: same keyword you have to search in both table on the basic of priority?m i right? can you write in details so that it would be easy to understand your question?

Comment: SELECT * from table 1 as a left join table2  as b on a.id=b.a_id where a.column1=? and b.clumn2=? and (MATCH(a.column1) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)>0 OR MATCH(b.column1) AGAINST (:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)>0 ) .

Comment: It seems so complicated.
My actual need is simple
I have a simple database with 2 tables
Table1- fields are "id"(varchar)- primary key; 
                    "mark_allow"(varchar),
                    "max_mark"(int)
Table2 -fields are "header" (varchar)-primary key;
                    "comment"(text); "school"(varchar)

Comment: I try to get a content from Table1 - "mark_allow" (example is 01, 012 or 014, 01345 etc) as a key,
then I want to look into Table2, using the "header" field which contain the corresponding
data (01, 012.... etc). Once it match, output the "comment" of that key using php.

The final output looks link

"mark_allow is " 013 "Please give 0, 1, or 3 marks"